# creating droplet using doctl and enable and customize user-data?

Tags: command-line-interface, digital-ocean

I can't seem to find in the documentation how to enable and specify user-data while using the command-line utility doctl to create a droplet. Is this possible?

Thanks,

Tom

Answer (score 0):

The answer is a somewhat undocumented flag "--user-data-file filename.txt"